# Cannot find name 'Routes'. Converting angular2 SPA into Ionic mobile app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular2-routing

I am trying to convert my already built angular2 web page app into mobile application using ionic framework. My aim is to achieve with little code modification.

Currently I am getting several errors while building my app and all are related to Router or Routes.

```
Cannot find name 'ActivatedRoute'.
Cannot find name 'Router'.       
Cannot find name 'Params'.
Cannot find name 'Routes'.
```

My code that works fine in angular is something like this

```
constructor(
    private ticketService:  TicketService,
    private route:          ActivatedRoute,
    private location:       Location
) { }
```

And it does not find modules like Routes, ActivatedRoute etc.

Following are my version information:

> ionic -version **3.1.2**
>
> npm --version **4.1.1**
>
> ng --version

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 6.9.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.1.0
@angular/compiler: 4.1.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.0
@angular/core: 4.1.0
@angular/forms: 4.1.0
@angular/http: 4.1.0
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.0
```

Is Router not available in ionic?

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Is **Route** module (and others) removed from **angular 4** ?

Comment: wow...! no reply :-(